# Scala: Parse yaml file in scala (types casting )

Tags: java, json, scala, yaml

I have a yaml file that I want to read its contents in scala , so I parse it using io.circe.yaml to json

```scala
var js = yaml.parser.parse(ymlText)
var json=js.valueOr(null)
var jsonstring=json.toString
val json2 = parse(jsonstring)
```

the yamltext is like this:

```yaml
ALL:
  Category1:
    Subcategory11 : 1.5
    Subcategory12 : 0
    Subcategory13 : 0
    Subcategory14  : 0.5
  Category2:
    Subcategory21 : 1.5
    Subcategory22 : 0.3
    Subcategory23 : 0
    Subcategory24  : 0
```

what I want is to filter the subcategories that has Zero values, I've used this code:

```scala
val elements = (json2 \\"ALL" ).children.map(x=>(x.values))
var subCategories=elements.map{case(a,b)=>(b)}
var cats=elements.map{case(a,b)=>(b.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Double]])}
cats.map(x=>x.filter{case(a,b)=>b>0.0})
```

But the last line gives me this error: 
**scala.math.BigInt cannot be cast to java.lang.Double**

Comment: What is your `parse` function in `val json2 = parse(jsonString)`. I'd like to assume it's circle.json.parser.parse, but circe's AST doesn't have a `children` field, so the code snippet you have at the bottom doesn't make sense with that assumption.

Comment: Have you inspected (by printing for example) at what stage the BigInts pop up instead of the doubles? When I parse your yaml with circe I am getting double.

Comment: In fact the second parse is to have the JValue instance , I have used it because i did not know the method (right.get) , Mr.SergGr gave me the answer I'am searching for.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you do `toString` + `parse` and which `parse` is used but you probably don't need it. Also you didn't describe your expected result so here are a few guesses of what you might need:

```
import java.io._
import io.circe._
import io.circe.yaml._
import io.circe.parser._

def test(): Unit = {
  // test data instead of a file
  val ymlText =
    """
      |ALL:
      |  Category1:
      |    Subcategory11 : 1.5
      |    Subcategory12 : 0
      |    Subcategory13 : 0
      |    Subcategory14  : 0.5
      |  Category2:
      |    Subcategory21 : 1.5
      |    Subcategory22 : 0.3
      |    Subcategory23 : 0
      |    Subcategory24  : 0
    """.stripMargin


  var js = yaml.parser.parse(new StringReader(ymlText))
  var json: Json = js.right.get

  val categories = (json \\ "ALL").flatMap(j => j.asObject.get.values.toList)
  val subs = categories.flatMap(j => j.asObject.get.toList)
  val elements: List[(String, Double)] = subs.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.asNumber.get.toDouble) }
    .filter {
      case (k, v) => v > 0.0
    }
  println(s"elements: $elements")

  val allCategories = (json \\ "ALL").flatMap(j => j.asObject.get.toList).toMap
  val filteredTree: Map[String, Map[String, Double]] = allCategories
    .mapValues(catJson => catJson.asObject.get.toList.map { case (subName, subJson) => (subName, subJson.asNumber.get.toDouble) }
      .filter { case (subName, subValue) => subValue > 0.0 }
      .toMap)
  println(s"filteredTree : $filteredTree")
}
```

And the output for that is:

> elements: List((Subcategory11,1.5), (Subcategory14,0.5), (Subcategory21,1.5), (Subcategory22,0.3))
>   
>   filteredTree : Map(Category1 -> Map(Subcategory11 -> 1.5, Subcategory14 -> 0.5), Category2 -> Map(Subcategory21 -> 1.5, Subcategory22 -> 0.3))

Hope one of those version is what you needed.

Comment: Thank you , my reason to use the second parse is to have the JValue instance, which was the only instance of json that I knew, so the method 
    var json: Json = js.right.get   is the key to the solution.
Any way your soulution is exactly hat I am looking for, our econd guess :) .
Thank you very much